Cómo encriptar lo que se escribe en un InputBox usando C#
Me gustaría saber la forma o manera de encriptar lo que se escribe en un inputbox en c#.


Hola Lisandro, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y en caso de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Sigo sin entender la razon de tu duda? puedes dar mas detalles de cual es tu objetivo, quizas se te puede dar una ide diferente pero funcional, por cierto incluye algo de tu codigo de lo que intentas realizar.

Lo que quieres hacer no es encriptación, sino más bien ocultar los caracteres para que no se vean mientras los vas escribiendo, para lograr esto lo que debes hacer es marcar el TextBox e ir al inspector de objetos, una vez allí vas a la propiedad PasswordChar y escribes el caracter por el que serán remplazados los caracteres que vas escribiendo, generalmente en la propiedad PasswordChar se escribe un asterisco ('*'), pero puedes escribir el carácter que desees.

wn winforms era igual que en wpf? faltaria esa aclaracion en la pregunta...

@gbianchi en la foto que pone, se ve que es Windows Form por el icono del formulario

gracias por tu respuesta amigo, pero no es precisamente la solución que busco gracias

@LisandroPedriquez si das mas detalles se te puede ayudar mejor
